# How to make the login error("Wrong username/password") be more specific in a Login Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm creating a login page with the use of JDBC, servlet and JSP. My problem is, I don't know how to make the login error more specific. For example, if the user enters a wrong username, then it will display "Wrong Username". If the user enters a wrong password, then it will display "Wrong Password"

I can only do "Wrong username/password"

Here's my code:

```
if(loginButton){
                    String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=? AND password=?";
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
                    String usernameInput= request.getParameter("usernameInput");
                    String passwordInput=request.getParameter("passwordInput");
                    String passwordEnc= encrypt(passwordInput);

                    ps.setString(1, usernameInput);
                    ps.setString(2, passwordEnc);

                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                    if(rs.next() && captcha.isCorrect(answer)){
                        if(rs.getString("role").equals("Admin")){
                            request.setAttribute("role", rs.getString("role"));
                            request.setAttribute("username", rs.getString("username"));
                            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("adminAccess.jsp");
                            view.forward(request, response);

                        }

                        else{
                            request.setAttribute("role", rs.getString("role"));
                            request.setAttribute("username", rs.getString("username"));
                            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("loginResult.jsp");
                            view.forward(request, response);
                        }

                   //response.sendRedirect("loginResult.jsp");

                    }else if(!captcha.isCorrect(answer)) {
                            request.setAttribute("captchaMismatch","Captcha does not match");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

                        }
                    else if(!rs.next()){
                            request.setAttribute("loginError","Wrong username/password!");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                        }

                }
```

Comment: You don't want to make the error message any more specific than that. The last thing you want to do is to provide clues to unauthorized users who are trying to hack your app.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Don't worry I would never do this. This is just a project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `else-if` you can change like below to achieve that  :

```
                  else if(!captcha.isCorrect(answer)) {
                            request.setAttribute("captchaMismatch","Captcha does not match");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

                        }
                  else {
                        String sql1 = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username=?";//getting username
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ps.setString(1,usernameInput);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
               //if row exist means username there in table
              if(rs.next())
                {
                    //getting password
                    String pass = rs.getString("password");
                    //checking if pass is not equal
                  if(!pass.equals(passwordEnc)){
                            request.setAttribute("loginError","Wrong password!");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                        }
                      }else{

                        request.setAttribute("loginError","Wrong username");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                     }

             }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should never do this. This leaks information about the existence of a username.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have no intentions of doing this if I ever create a website that has a login page. This is just part of a project.